# What is the easiest way to get AB-testing with Marathon & Mesos?

Tags: marathon

What is the easiest way to get AB-testing with Marathon & Mesos?

We're currently investigating an enterprise solution called vamp, but if there are any good open source solutions, that'd be great to know.

Answer (score -1):

*DISCLAIMER : I work for Mesosphere so my answer might not be most unbiased*

DC/OS is an open-source solution that comes with Mesos/Marathon and much more out of the box :

- https://github.com/dcos/
- https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/installing/

There is a [Mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/dcos.io/forum/#!forum/users) and [Slack Comuunity](http://chat.dcos.io/) to help you get started

Mesosphere also has an Enterprise solution which comes with a bunch of closed source security features and support. But DC/OS is an "open core" product. Feature Comparison between OSS and Enterprise